# React then returns cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on the app that uses Youtube to return list of videos. In order to query youtube API I use `youtube-api-search` npm module. Aplication takes term from searchbar, passes it to app, then method is called that activates search. Inside `Youtube.js` file console.log returns array of 5 videos as expected, however when I chain then back in app.js I got an error - cannot read property of undefined.

```js
//App.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import  SearchBar from '../Searchbar/Searchbar';
import VideoList from '../VideoList/VideoList';
import Youtube from '../../utils/Youtube';


class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      videos: []
    }
    this.searchYoutube = this.searchYoutube.bind(this);
  }
  
  searchYoutube(term) {
    Youtube.search(term)
    .then(videos => {
      // console.log("app videos", video);
      this.setState({
        videos: videos
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
       <SearchBar onSearch={this.searchYoutube} />
       <VideoList videos={this.state.videos}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;

//Youtube.js
import YTSearch from 'youtube-api-search';
const API = 'xxxxx';

const Youtube = {
    search(term) {
        return YTSearch({ key: API, term: term }, (data) => {
            return data.map(video => {
                console.log('youtube title: ', video.snippet.title);
                return {
                    title: video.snippet.title,
                    url: video.snippet.thumbnails.default.url,
                    description: video.snippet.description,
                    id: video.etag
                }
            });
        });
    }


}

export default Youtube;

//Searchbar.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Searchbar.css';

class SearchBar extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            term: ''
        }
        this.inputSearch = this.inputSearch.bind(this);
        this.handleSearch = this.handleSearch.bind(this);
    }
    inputSearch(e) {
        this.setState({
            term: e.target.value
        });
    }
    handleSearch(e) {
        this.props.onSearch(this.state.term);
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="row">
               
                    <input type="text" onChange={this.inputSearch} className="input_searchbar" id="inlineFormInput" placeholder="Enter search term" />

                    <button onClick={this.handleSearch} className="button_searchbar ">Submit</button>

            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default SearchBar;
```

Comment: `cannot read property of undefined.` is that the full error? Does it not say the name of the property?

Comment: why do you publish inherited methods to own properties?

Comment: the full error is:App.js:18 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
    at App.searchYoutube (App.js:18)
    at SearchBar.handleSearch (Searchbar.js:19)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-......

Comment: @dandavis: what do you mean?

Comment: why do you need `this.searchYoutube = this.searchYoutube.bind(this);`?

Comment: @dandavis presumably in order to properly bind `this`, so that it works correctly when executed as a callback. Note that `searchYoutube` needs to call `this.setState`, which will fail if `this` is undefined (in strict mode) or the window object

Comment: @NicholasTower: i get that, but aren't prototype methods bound to the same `this` as instances? and don't "fat arrows" freeze `this`? i can see no diff in a stripped-down example. seems overwritten...

Comment: `aren't prototype methods bound to the same this as instances?` I'm not sure what you mean. By default, methods are not bound at all. `and don't "fat arrows" freeze this` Yes, creating an arrow function would be another option instead of creating a function via this.searchYoutube.bind(this)

Answer (score 3):

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Since the only instance of .then in your code follows a call to Youtube.search, then Youtube.search most not be returning a promise, which in turn means that YTSearch is not returning a promise. It looks like it's intended to be a callback api, not a promise api, so you'll need to wrap it in a promise yourself:

```
const Youtube = {
  search(term) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      YTSearch({ key: API, term: term }, (data) => {
        resolve(data.map(video => {
            return {
              title: video.snippet.title,
              url: video.snippet.thumbnails.default.url,
              description: video.snippet.description,
              id: video.etag
            };
        }));
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: that exactly what i was missing, thanks @Nicholas Tower